# UILabel centered text CGRect?

Tags: swift, uilabel

I have a UILabel with centered text. Single line, not attributed. I want to get the CGRect for the actual text in the label (it spans the whole width of a iOS device). Some of the text is dynamic in the text, so the width of the text in the label can change from time to time. So I want to get the position of the text so that I can place an image next to the first character.

I did this in the past but can't remember what I did to do it.

Comment: Why not using NSAttributedString to render the image, and NSParagraphStyle to add a headindent equals to the width of the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using UILabel.textRect. It works perfectly for me.

```
let myRect:CGRect = _topBanner.textRect(forBounds: _topBanner.bounds, limitedToNumberOfLines: 1)
_icon.frame.origin.x = myRect.origin.x - _icon.frame.size.width + 50
_icon.frame.origin.y = _topBanner.frame.origin.y + 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a temporary `UILabel` just to get the text *width*:

```
let fullWidthLabel: UILabel = ...
let tmpLabel = UILabel()
tmpLabel.text = fullWidthLabel.text
tmpLabel.font = fullWidthLabel.font
tmpLabel.sizeToFit()
let textWidth = tmpLabel.frame.width
```

Use `textWidth` to solve your original problem.